# How do I can connect to my stun server?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, stun, simplehttpserver

I had to build a stun server via open source. 
[stund](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stun/)

But I can't access my stun server.
Here my Code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Your local IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your public IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your IPv6 addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        <script>
            //get the IP addresses associated with an account
            function getIPs(callback){
                var ip_dups = {};
                //compatibility for firefox and chrome
                var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                    || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
                if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                    //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                    //
                    //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                    //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                    //
                    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                    RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                        || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                        || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                    useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                }
                //minimal requirements for data connection
                var mediaConstraints = {
                    optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
                };
                //my stun server ip
                var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:39.xxx.xxx.xxx"}]};
        
                //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
                var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
                function handleCandidate(candidate){
                    //match just the IP address
                    var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                    var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
                    //remove duplicates
                    if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                        callback(ip_addr);
                    ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
                }
                //listen for candidate events
                pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
                    //skip non-candidate events
                    if(ice.candidate)
                        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
                };
                //create a bogus data channel
                pc.createDataChannel("");
                //create an offer sdp
                pc.createOffer(function(result){
                    //trigger the stun server request
                    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
                }, function(){});
                //wait for a while to let everything done
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //read candidate info from local description
                    var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
                    lines.forEach(function(line){
                        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                            handleCandidate(line);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
            //insert IP addresses into the page
            getIPs(function(ip){
             console.log(ip);
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = ip;
                //local IPs
                if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
                //IPv6 addresses
                else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);
                //assume the rest are public IPs
                else
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This source and run a python SimpleHTTPServer but connected via a web browser , there was no response. How can I be connected to stun server via a web browser?

also I try test Client test site provided by Google
http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
but same problom:(

Comment: What do you mean by can't access? Have you tried a simple telnet on the server on port 3478? If you're using a different port than you should specify it in the config.

Comment: Yes I can. I tried telnet on the server on port 3478. There was work by StuntMan TCP Stun server

Comment: You did edit your stun server address via the field at "stun:39.xxx.xxx.xxx", right?